# Adding text on each bar of histogram

Tags: d3.js

I have problem adding text in my histogram. I can do this in more simple example.

I try to do this:

```
// try to add bar value  
var barnum = g.selectAll('text')
              .data(layout)
              .enter()
              .append("text")
              .attr('y',-10)
              .attr('x',10)
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("fill","black")
              .text('testtest')
              .style("pointer-events", "none")
        ;
  barnum.transition();
```

I can't see any text in my figure. The code include definition is here:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
  var g;
  var data;
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 80},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var cx = 10;
  var numberBins = 5;
  var dispatch = d3.dispatch(chart, "hover");

  function chart(container) {
    g = container;

    update();
  }
  chart.update = update;
  function update() {

    // create hist layout
    var hist = d3.layout.histogram()
                  .value(function(d) { return d.selectvar })
                  .range([d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.selectvar }) ,           d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.selectvar }) ])
                  .bins(numberBins);
    var layout = hist(data);

    var maxLength = d3.max(layout, function(d) { return d.length });
    var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                      .domain([0, maxLength])
                      .range([0, width])

    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(d3.range(numberBins))
                  .rangeBands([height, 0], 0)

    var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();

    // create svg 
    var rects = g.selectAll("rect")
                .data(layout)

    rects.enter().append("rect")

    rects .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .attr({
            y: function(d,i) {
              return yScale(i)
            },
            x: 50,
            height: yScale.rangeBand(),
            width: function(d,i) {
              return widthScale(d.length)
            },
            fill: function(d, i) { return colorScale(i) }
          });

    rects.exit().transition().remove();


// try to add bar value  
    var barnum = g.selectAll('text')
                  .data(layout)
                  .enter()
                  .append("text")
                  .attr('y',-10)
                  .attr('x',10)
                  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .style("fill","black")
                  .text('testtest')
                  .style("pointer-events", "none")
            ;
      barnum.transition();
```

is there something wrong with my way to create svg element? I found out some successful case use append('g') from the beginning. New to d3.js! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `d3.dispatch`, which is documented on a page titled [Internals](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch). That doesn't mean you shouldn't use it, but rather, it shouldn't be your first choice.

You're correct that there's "something wrong with my way to create svg element" -- you're not creating one! Try:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var g = svg.append("g");
```

At this point, you need to have a good understanding of the DOM, the SVG standard, CSS selectors, and D3's selection API to make things work. You don't tell D3 to put labels on your bars and that's it. You have to instruct it what elements to create, and where, keeping track of translates and offsets and stuff like that. You're best off copying and studying one of Mike Bostock's [many examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450).

D3 is not learned quickly. You need to invest time learning it before you can make any chart you like.

Comment: Thank for information. Actually This is one example from Mike Bostock. It append 'svg' and 'g' in outer loop in html. So inside update function. g was already an 'svg' element appended with 'g'. But you are right I don't know the exact meaning of 'svg' or 'g' and when we should append them :(

Comment: If you link to the original example I might be able to figure out what he's doing.